# How can I safely pass my API-key and email credentials needed for my python function?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I created a simple application that just sends me an email about the weather for the location I choose. It works as expected locally, but now I need to figure out how to pass my API-Key and email log-in credentials safely. At the moment, I have them in a .env file and I don't want it exposed on GitHub. Since I'm using Azure DevOps as my CI/CD pipeline, do I pass those in there? I'm having my pipeline build a docker image and not sure how to pass a variable into a dockerfile build. Here's my dockerfile:

```
# Copy function code
COPY app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Avoid cache purge by adding requirements first
COPY requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ARG WEATHER_API_KEY
ARG EMAIL_USER
ARG EMAIL_PASSWORD
ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
ARG AWS_DEFAULT_REGION

ENV WEATHER_API_KEY $WEATHER_API_KEY
ENV EMAIL_USER $EMAIL_USER
ENV EMAIL_PASSWORD $EMAIL_PASSWORD
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_REGION $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

Comment: Which cloud provider (if any) are you using to host your application? Some providers such as Azure and AWS provide secret management services, which would be an another approach to providing these variables at runtime rather than baking them in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should neither source control secrets nor add them to the image. Both ways are insecure.

A common practice is to read the env variables at runtime. You provide those when running your container.

```sh
export API_KEY="$(some-cli get-key mykey)"
docker run -e API_KEY myimage
```

Or set it directly, although then you have it in the history.

```sh
docker run -e API_KEY="foobar" myimage
```

Then your code needs to read the variables from `os.environ` rather than a .env file.

Depending on how you run your container this may look different but the general idea remains the same.